# human handoff Conversation transfero admin

Tags: python, llama, llama-index, chat-gpt-4

I'm implementing a custom ChatGPT using LLM-index. I want to transfer the chat to the admin if the user asks anything about talking to the admin. Additionally, I want to store booking data (date, time, name) in a variable so that the user can inquire about these details at any time, and it should track them. I don't know how to do it or if it's doable.

How can I implement it in Python? Is it doable?

Comment: Show us what you have implemented so far, even if it does not yet work properly.